# How to ignore the White spaces and new lines in XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have an XML file where i will be looping throught the nodes and will get the values of the Attributes.

But along with the attribute values i am also getting some symbols(rectangular box) in the output. If i try removing the space
between tags then it was fine.

In the below XML i am getting the innertext of title.

```
 <catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
   <details>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </details>
  </book>
  </catalog>
```

It was fine if my input is like this:

```
  <catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
   <details><title>XML Developer's Guide</title></details>
   </book>
  </catalog>
```

I am using C#

```
 foreach (XmlNode catalogid in Xmlcontent.GetElementsByTagName("catalog"))
      {
        foreach (XmlNode bookid in catalogid)
                    {
                        foreach (XmlNode titleid in bookid)
                        {
                       string booktitle = titleid.InnerText.ToString();
                        }
                     }
      }
```

Please suggest how can i ignore the White spaces and new lines in my output.

Comment: Please show the code you're currently using, and say what language and platform you're using (Java, J2EE?)

Comment: you can remove spaces by using `string.Trim()` and `string.Remove(' ')` also `string.Remove('\r')` and `string.Remove('\n')` or `string.Remove("\r\n")`

Comment: Please do not parse yourself XML. Its quite serious task which was solved successfully many times by writers of XML library. There free tool just use it.

Comment: Here good sample imho: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you restricted to using .Net 2.0?  If so ignore the following.

If you can use .Net 3.5 then the following Linq-To-Xml will work for you.

1. First load the file
2. Get all Catalog elements like you did
3. Then select all the books of a catalog
4. Get the books id & title
5. Assign all the books from all the catalogs into one variable books as an array.

.

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
var catalogs = root.Descendants("catalog");
var books = catalogs.SelectMany(c => 
    c.Descendants("book").Select(book => new
    {
        Id = book.Attribute("id").Value,
        Title = book.Descendants("title").First().Value
    }))
    //.OrderBy(b => b.Title)  // sort by title or id if you'd like.
    .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code based on `PreserveWhitespace`  property

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
....
....
doc.PreserveWhitespace = false;
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.preservewhitespace.aspx